# How to alter the clustered index on a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, innodb

How to alter the clustered index on a mysql table? (InnoDB)

Also how to show the current clustered index on a table?

Comment: Did my answer below help at all? Any upvote or Acceptance with a green check mark, or should I delete? Don't forget to accept answers on your questions. It encourages people in the future to answer them.